# Delete all objects from a directory in google storage bucket using cloud storage options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-bucket

I'm using cloud storage options from google cloud to manage data in a GCP bucket. I've a directory under which I want to delete all the objects before I start writing new objects.
sample directory: gs://bucket-name/directory1/subdirectory/

I'm able to delete a single object using the following code, but how do I get list of all the objects in a directory and delete all of them?

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
public class DeleteObject {
       public static void deleteObject(String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName) {
       // The ID of your GCP project
       // String projectId = "your-project-id";

      // The ID of your GCS bucket
      // String bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name";

     // The ID of your GCS object
     // String objectName = "your-object-name";

     Storage storage = 
     StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
     storage.delete(bucketName, objectName);

     System.out.println("Object " + objectName + " was deleted from " + bucketName);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over `objects` in the `bucket` with a prefix of the directory name.

See the following snippet:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
Page<Blob> blobs =
storage.list(
        bucketName,
        Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(directoryPrefix), // directoryPrefix is the sub directory. 
        Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());
    
for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
  blob.delete(Blob.BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());
}
```

---

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-java
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#code-sample
- https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-storage/latest/com.google.cloud.storage.Blob

Comment: This worked, but it also deleted the subdirectory. How do I only delete the objects and not the subdirectory?

Comment: @Dookoto_Sea folders does not exist in object storage systems like Cloud Storage. Please first check and understand how it works https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Comment: Exactly, directories are not real. You said in your case that every time you add new objects, you need to do a clean up. so it won't be an issue if you uploaded objects with the required prefix again.